# Is it dangerous for the pc desktop health to remove a couple of PCI slot covers from the case?

Tags: pci-express

I'd like to know if could be dangerous for the pc health to remove the backside steel pci covers, since I lost a couple of them.
Could the dust be filled inside even if it's a miditower and so it's placed vertically?

Comment: You do know that you can purchase extra flanges for those slots cheap-cheap-cheap, right?  If you really worry about it, do so.  It will at least keep the not-too-tiny critters out and might help the airflow depending on where the fans are placed.

Answer (score 1):

Most PC cases are so badly designed it's unlikely to make the slightest bit of difference.

Technically, it prevents a well-designed airflow from functioning at its optimum potential - but most simply don't **have** a well-designed airflow in the first place; they push warm air out the back & rely on whatever holes are left anywhere else to let the cool air in.
Even ones with dedicated fans at the front tend to blow randomly through a rack with an unknown number of drives in the way.

I wouldn't let it worry you.

Comment: Thanks, well actually mine is a naxt s340 elite and it should have a very good design? Isn't it? So, we can conclude no dust or in the worst case there is just a slightly difference that won't affect the pc inside.

Comment: I have one similar - let's say it's "better than most" but not by much. Have a look inside an old Mac Pro case if you want to see efficient airflow - 3 'channels' one for each section of the case & components. No-one else has ever come close.

Answer (score 1):

Can it let in more dust? Yes.

Is that dust likely to immediately try to get into "dangerous" places? No.

Is that dust likely to build up to the extent that fans become completely ineffective? Not unless you live in a permanent thick cloud of dust yourself.

Can small creatures climb through the gaps, be unable to escape and die in your case? Well, yes. And the worst that is likely to happen is that your PC "smells funny".

Depending on the case design and airflow inside it might mean you have some extra vents in or out of the case. Extra dust might be pulled in or pushed out and it can affect the cooling in some probably very minor ways.

In the same way that you should regularly check the oil and tyre pressures on your car you should very occasionally give any PC a quick glance to make sure it doesn't have any large buildups of dust or other junk. It's good practice and can be a simple way to quickly check that fans are clear, spinning and not making noise or require replacement.

Comment: Wow...the little creatures scare me. But even if I put, in my case, the two slot covers, my nzxt s340 has a lot of holes, so even in that case the small creatures could get inside. Is there a way to prevent this danger?

Comment: Small creatures is only a problem if you regularly loose mice or hamsters (they can squeeze through surprisingly small gaps) or have some kind of vermin infestation. The "risk" is incredibly small and mitigated by having a clean environment. People find creatures living in all sorts of odd environments like car bodywork or boxes left outside. I only mentioned it because of some of the "computer cleaning" horror stories where people have left a computer on (or off) in a corner for years without cleaning and found spiders or other creatures set up home.